# How to list all the <td> inside the <tr> tag using selenium webDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 16 `<td>` tag for each `<tr>` .
I use the following but don't work for me

```
List < WebElement > implantToBePlaced = driver.findElements(By.id("teethChart-Maxilla-Implants"));
for (int i = 0; i < implantToBePlaced.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("td")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: i have the exception "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
"

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `WebElement` list using ***`for each`***

I assume `List<WebElement> implantToBePlaced` are rows collection.

```
List<WebElement> implantToBePlaced = driver.findElements(By.id("teethChart-Maxilla-Implants"));
for(WebElement row: implantToBePlaced) {
    List<WebElement> tds = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for(WebElement td: tds) {
        td.click();
    }
}
```